# Increment browser cookie in Javascript? (setCookie, getCookie method)

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

Logically this seems to be correct. However, either the setCookie or getCookie functions simply aren't firing?

cookie.js

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays) { var exdate=new Date();
exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays); var c_value=escape(value) +
((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value; }

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));
}
return c_value;
}
```

index.php

```
var newCookie = parseInt(getCookie("liked_count"));
if(newCookie != null && newCookie != ""){
newCookie += 1;
setCookie("liked_count",newCookie,5);
}else{
setCookie("liked_count",1,5);
}
```

No matter which side of the if statement it follows, no cookie is set regardless. From what I can tell there are no errors or warnings, so could it be that it cannot find the setCookie and getCookie function inside the my cookies.js file?

The cookies.js file successfully locates, so I'm at my wits end here.

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/cookies.js"></script>
</head>
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT:

Oh sorry, this is embarrassing... It turns out that the cookie.js file was being cached and I had actually moved file location. It was that simple. Sorry for this waste of time!

Comment: The easiest way to tell if functions are firing is to have them output something to the console using `console.log`. You could also `alert`, but that's a bit more obtrusive!

Comment: Nothing shows up in console.log, but when I inspect element in-browser the code is shown to be there.

Comment: Could you put this up in a jsFiddle?

Comment: Oh sorry, this is embarrassing... It turns out that the cookie.js file was being cached and I had actually moved file location. It was that simple. Sorry for this waste of time!

Comment: I think you're still going to have a problem, you should take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is with your use of:

```
var newCookie = parseInt(getCookie("liked_count"));
```

[MDN parseInt Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

parseInt returns NaN if it fails. Instead of the following line:

```
if(newCookie != null && newCookie != ""){
```

you should have

```
if(!isNaN(newCookie)) {
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/2Nj5pj

Comment: It still worked regardless, but this way is cleaner and likely more compatible. Thank you!